# Ingress creating health check on HTTP instead of TCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I am actually trying to run 3 containers in my gke cluster. I have them exposed via a network load balancer and over that, I am using ingress so I can reach my services from different domains with SSL certs on them.

Here is the complete manifest

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app:web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: us-east4-docker.pkg.dev/web:e856485      # docker image
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: production
---
# DEPLOYMENT MANIFEST #
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cms
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cms
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cms
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cms
        image: us-east4-docker.pkg.dev/cms:4e1fe2f      # docker image
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8055
        env:
        - name  : DB
          value : "postgres"

        - name  : DB_HOST
          value : 10.142.0.3

        - name  : DB_PORT
          value : "5432"
---
# DEPLOYMENT MANIFEST #
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api
        image: us-east4-docker.pkg.dev/api:4e1fe2f      # docker image
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name  : HOST
          value : "0.0.0.0"

        - name  : PORT
          value : "8080"
     
        - name  : NODE_ENV
          value : production
---
# SERVICE MANIFEST #
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-lb
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: web
  type: NodePort
---
# SERVICE MANIFEST #
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cms-lb
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
  labels:
    app: cms
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8055
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8055
  selector:
    app: cms
  type: NodePort
---
# SERVICE MANIFEST #
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-lb
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: api
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  tls.crt: abc
  tls.key: abc
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: web-cert
type: kubernetes.io/tls
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  tls.crt: abc
  tls.key: abc
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: cms-cert
type: kubernetes.io/tls
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  tls.crt: abc
  tls.key: abc
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: api-cert
type: kubernetes.io/tls
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    # If the class annotation is not specified it defaults to "gce".
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: api-cert
  - secretName: cms-cert
  - secretName: web-cert
  rules:
  - host: web-gke.dev
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: web-lb
            port:
              number: 3000
  - host: cms-gke.dev
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: cms-lb
            port:
              number: 8055
  - host: api-gke.dev
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: api-lb
            port:
              number: 8080
```

The containers are accessible through the load balancer(network), but from ingress(L7 lb) the health check is failing[image: Ingress showing unhealthy services].

I tried editing the health checks manually from HTTP:80 to TCP:8080/8055/3000 for 3 services and it works.[image: ALB failing health checks]

But eventually, ingress reverts it back to HTTP health check and it fails again. I also tried using NodePort instead of load balancer as service type but no luck.
Any help?

Comment: There is no real benefit to using serviceType Loadbalancer AND Ingress, you are just creating multiple Google Load balancers. If your service requires plain TCP traffic, just use the LoadBalancers. If you want layer 7 routing, change the services to NodePort and keep the Ingress

Comment: yeah i am using nodeport for services. let me edit the codeblock

Comment: @SohaibMustafa has the answer below solved your issue?

Comment: Yes somehow it has. It was not the issue with Port or protocol but the health check location. It wasn't giving 200 on / So I had to change it to the actual path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I would like to mention is that you need to recheck your implementation because from what I see, you are creating an `Ingress` which will create a `LoadBanacer`, and this `Ingress` is using three services of type `LoadBalancer` in which each one of them will also create its `LoadBalancer` (I'm assuming the default behaviour, unless you applied the famous workaround of deleting the `service`'s `LoadBalancer` manually after it is created).

And I don't think this is correct unless you need that design for some reason. So, my suggestion is that you might want to change your services types to `NodePort`.

---

As for answering your question, what you are missing is:

You need to implement a `BackendConfig` with custom `HealthCheck` configurations.

1- Create the `Backendconfig`:

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: api-lb-backendconfig
spec:
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: INTERVAL
    timeoutSec: TIMEOUT
    healthyThreshold: HEALTH_THRESHOLD
    unhealthyThreshold: UNHEALTHY_THRESHOLD
    type: PROTOCOL
    requestPath: PATH
    port: PORT
```

2- Use this config in your service/s

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {
    "PORT_NAME_1":"api-lb-backendconfig"
    }}'
spec:
  ports:
  - name: PORT_NAME_1
    port: PORT_NUMBER_1
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: TARGET_PORT
```

Once you apply such configurations, your `Ingress`'s `LoadBalanacer` will be created with the `BackendConfig` *"api-lb-backendconfig"*

---

Consider [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features) documentation page as your reference.

Comment: You are right for most part of my question, but just one more thing. How can I create health check over TCP? I can see this available over the console but according to this link I cannot create health check for TCP protocol.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#direct_health

Comment: This is true simply because the health checks requires an HTTP response to perform the health check. Since you are using an ingress (layer 7) the assumption is that you are exposing a web service, HTTP would be the go to type, and for the port, choose the port you are using (does not need to be 80 or 8080). The health check just needs a 200 response from which ever port it targets

Comment: Ok, I get your point, but is there a way if I want to configure health check on TCP instead of HTTP? I can see this is possible from the console but I am unable to do this using Kubernetes config file

Comment: @SohaibMustafa as Patrick highlighted The health check needs to get an HTTP 200 (OK) response. So it doesn't matter which port you are using, the response has to be HTTP 200 (OK). See [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#health_checks) for more details. 
I suggest you try to create the `health check` and then check how it looks like from the cloud console

Comment: @SohaibMustafa  Is it possible to configure health check with TCP ?

The issue we are facing now is when the health check takes place on contour envoy pods, the target is on nodeport 30837, but the protocol used is HTTP and thus failing the health check, i can manually change it to TCP from the UI it works but the changes get reverted to HTTP after a while.
How can i create a custom health check with protocol as TCP,  i tried creating custom health check as in doc https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#direct_health which throws the below error:

Comment: Error syncing to GCP: error running backend syncing routine: error ensuring health check: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.tcpHealthCheck': ''. TCP healthCheck missing., invalid